# Backend Error after moving a PrestaShop website from one host to another

Tags: prestashop

I'm moving this website http://farmtrust.tn built using `PrestaShop` in a new Hosting provider. This is the new URL http://shop.farmtruster.com. And now when I try to access the admin back-end I get a `FatalErrorException`.

[image: this is what I got when I try to access the website]

```
FatalErrorException
Compile Error: Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader::loadClass(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RegisterCsrfTokenClearingLogoutHandlerPass.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/var/www/html/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/var/www/html/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/www/html/vendor/pear/archive_tar:.:/usr/share/php')

in DebugClassLoader.php line 156
```

Also, the site is not functioning http://shop.farmtruster.com it shows Not Found.

The requested URL was not found on this server.

I'm trying to host in AWS in an EC2 instance I've installed `xampp` first but then it stopped suddenly functioning so I installed manually PHP MySQL apache...

The website files are in `var/www/html` folder Note that http://shop.farmtruster.com redirects me to http://shop.farmtruster.com/fr/ so I've concluded that traduction is working. 
I hope you can help me

Comment: Have you cleared cache?

Comment: Yes, i cleared the cache of my browser and the cache of prestashop

Comment: Have you modified the ps_shop_url?

Comment: Yes it was redirecting to the old website and after I modified the ps_shop_url it stopped ridirecting and I got 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Debug steps:

1. Check if that .php file does exist in that location, if not copy it (them) over from the original Prestashop archive.
2. Remove the var/cache completely, it'll get recreated.
3. Check the files and directories ownership/permissions. The owner should be the apache user and the permissions 0755 for directories and 0644 for the files.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a custom module
this was in the beginning of the module:
`require_once './vendor/autoload.php';`

changed it to `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

and it works now